# How to wrap var in span or div tag?

Tags: jquery

I have the following code and I want to wrap index into `<span></span>` tags.

```
$('h2.carousel-item-title').each(function (index, value) {
  var content = '<span class = "wrap"></span>';
  var tab_number= $(this).append(index+1).wrap( content );
  return tab_number;
});
```

But it didn't work.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What "it didn't work" means in your case?

Comment: no it didn't work but i found solution :<br>$('.carousel-item-title').each(function (index, value) {
    var num= index+1;
   $(this).append("<span class='num'>"+num+"</span>");
});

Answer (score 0):

I have made the changes to your snippet to get it working.

Use:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('.carousel-item-title').each(function (index, value) {
  console.log('query');
    var content = '<span class = "wrap"></span>';
    var tab_number= $(this).append(index+1).wrap( content );
    return tab_number;});
    });
```

The complete code is here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title</title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('.carousel-item-title').each(function (index, value) {
  console.log('query');
    var content = '<span class = "wrap"></span>';
    var tab_number= $(this).append(index+1).wrap( content );
    return tab_number;});
    });

</script>
</head>
<body>

 <h2 class="carousel-item-title"> A
 </h2>

<h2 class="carousel-item-title"> B
</h2>
<h2 class="carousel-item-title"> C
</h2>
<h2 class="carousel-item-title"> D
</h2>
```